# I Getting null Response From sabre service GetReservation

Tags: c#, sabre

I am getting **null** response from sabre web service when call **GetReservation** Request

```
<GetReservationRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.18.0">
  <Locator xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18">Its Unique </Locator>
  <RequestType xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18">Stateful</RequestType>
  <ReturnOptions xsi:type="ReturnOptions" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18">
    <ViewName>VaDefaultWithPq</ViewName>
  </ReturnOptions>
</GetReservationRQ>
```

in this **ReturnOptions** tag one more element is missing is **ResponseFormate** that default value is **STL** so thats why it can not show on xml writing.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you are using "It's Unique" as a record locator? You should put a valid record locator there or delete the node if you are reading a PNR you have in your work area.

Can you post the Sabre endpoint you are pointing your application to?